# After ajax success and load specific div the content disappeared

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I am making an event calendar. After adding an event, only the cells of the calendar will be load after insertion of the data is successful. Adding event is fine but when div loaded the content disappear. Here's my code:

*** Ajax ***

```
$('.savedata').on('click', function () {
                // alert('savedata');
                var testchecked = $('#testchecked').val();
                var testingcheck = $('#testingcheck').val();
                $.ajax({
                    type : "POST",
                    url  : "<?php echo site_url()?>/CalendarController/savedata",
                    // dataType : "JSON",
                    data : { testchecked : testchecked, testingcheck : testingcheck },
                    success: function(data){
                        // alert('success');
                        //console.log('asd '+data);

                        $('#events-modal').modal('hide');
                        // cal-month-box
                        // $(".cal-month-day").append(JSON.stringify(data));
                        // $(".cal-month-day").load(window.location + " .cal-month-day");
                        // $('.cal-month-day').prepend(_newData);
                        $(".cal-month-day").load(location.href + " .cal-month-day");
                    },
                    error : function(data, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                        console.log(data.status);
                    }
                    });
                });
```

*** Before adding data ***

[image]

*** after adding event ***

[image]

*** Here's the HTML ***

[image]

*** Controller ***

```
public function savedata()
    {
        $this->load->view('calendarView');

        $this->em->form_insert();

    }
```

*** Model ***

```
function form_insert()
    {
        $abc            = $this->input->post('testchecked');

        $array = array('id' => $abc);
        $this->db->select("*");
        $this->db->where($array);
        $query = $this->db->get('dev_adkt_events_type');
        $response = $query->result_array();
        foreach($response as $res){
            $title = $res['id'];
        }


        $url            = 'URL';
        $class          = $this->input->post('testchecked');
        $start_date     = $this->input->post('testingcheck');
        $end_date       = $this->input->post('testingcheck');

        $data = array(
            'title'     => $title,
            'url'       => $url,
            'class'     => $class,
            'start_date'=> $start_date ,
            'end_date'  => $end_date 
        );

        // $this->db->insert('event',$data);
        $result = $this->db->insert('event',$data);
        return $result;

    }
```

Hope you could help me guys. Thank you in advance.

*** Displaying the Calendar ***

***Controller***

```
public function index() {
        $this->load->helper('url');
        // var_dump($postData);
        $result['eventcatresult'] = $this->em->geteventcategory();
        $result['data'] = $this->em->getevent();
        $result['data'] = $this->em->getnotes();

        $this->load->view('calendarView',$result);
    }
```

*** Model ***

```
function getevent()
    {
        $this->db->select("*");
        $query = $this->db->get($this->event);
        if ($query) {
            return $query->result();
        }
        return NULL;
    }
```

Comment: Can we see your HTML? Why do you think it's not relevant?

Comment: The simplest explanation would be that `form.html(msg)` overwrites the entire html of the calendar. instead of a specific node. Seems you just updated the code to `$(".cal-month-day").load(location.href + " .cal-month-day");`, which would make more sense.

Comment: can you share your controller from where you are loading calendar at first and show savedata function too

Comment: @M.Hemant okay sir

Comment: @M.Hemant i already updated my question sir

Comment: and what is in `location.href` can you share it here And where is the controller function from your calendar is loading at the first time?

Comment: @M.Hemant I am just trying every sir. Okay i will update it again sir.

Comment: Can you reload entire page instead of `.load(location.href + " .cal-month-day");`

Comment: @M.Hemant i should not reload the whole page coz it will be back at the current month sir.

Comment: why is there data overlapping in $result['data'] = $this->em->getevent();
        $result['data'] = $this->em->getnotes(); instead of $result['eventdata'] = $this->em->getevent();
        $result['notedata'] = $this->em->getnotes();

Answer (score 0):

you better change this

```
$(".cal-month-day").load(location.href + " .cal-month-day");
```

to this

```
$("#calendar").load(location.href + " #calendar");
```

because you have multiple `'cal-month-day'` for every event  and if the last element empty your all elements will be empty
better refresh all calendar

Comment: When i used it sir the whole calendar disappear

Comment: sorry for the being late for reply. try to change this $("#calendar").load(location.href + " #calendar"); to $("#calendarArea").load(location.href + " #calendar"); and add calendarArea id to span9 class

Comment: it's the same sir. the calendar just disappear :(